Carrier thermostat upgrade
Looking to upgrade the old Carrier 2 stage thermostat with a new smart Honeywell T9 Smart Thermostat. The Carrier thermostat is a Comfort Zone 2 and has only 4 wires, V+, VG, RS+ ad RS-. Is there a way to add the Honeywell in place of this Carrier without running additional wires?

Can you provide a model number for your furnace/air-handler please?
